# how to make bubble size smaller for only one word using 9 patch image android?

Tags: android

I am using 9 patch image for bubble color in android chat application and i want to reduce the size of 9 patch image to minimum,when there is only one word but, now bubble is too big for  any small text or a word ,in case of large text it is fine.

Comment: then design your bubble very small in Photoshop

Comment: i have tried that but didn't worked